# How to add mdframed in footer?

Tags: header-footer, mdframed

I am working on `fancyhdr` in report generation. Currently I am using `fancyhdr` which produces one line and I can add left, center and right footers below to this line. But I need an `mdframed` as footer and need to add right, left and middle text inside it.

Below is sample `mdframed` which need to be added as footer.

[image]

Please help me out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use something like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[C]{%
\begin{mdframed}[linecolor=blue!60,roundcorner=3pt]
\parbox[t]{0.333\textwidth}{\raggedright Text on the left}%
\parbox[t]{0.333\textwidth}{\centering Text on the center}%
\parbox[t]{0.333\textwidth}{\raggedleft Text on the right}
\end{mdframed}%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-12]
\end{document}
```

The idea is to place an `mdframed` environment centered in the footer; inside this environment, three `\parbox`es of equal length are used to place the footer contents. An image of the footer on the first page:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The [`tcolorbox` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) is another option to to produce rounded corner boxes, even in the footer:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{tcolorbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox
\pagestyle{fancy}
  \fancyhf{}% Clear headers/footers
  \fancyfoot[C]{%
    \begin{tcolorbox}[width=\linewidth]
      \makebox[0pt][l]{Text on the left}\hfill%
      \makebox[0pt][c]{Text on the center}\hfill%
      \makebox[0pt][r]{Text on the right}%
    \end{tcolorbox}%
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-12]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, both solutions are good and quite useful for my work.